# Implementation of interface

Tags: c++, oop, interface, implementation

I have an interface and some implementations. But in one implementation i have a specify functionality using only in that implementation.

```
class Interface
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
}

class D1 : public Interface
{
    void foo() {}
}

class D2 : public Interface
{
    void foo() {}
    void bar() {}
}
```

So i have a D2::bar() function only in D2, and it specified only for D2 implementation. 
What is the right way using OOP to write that kind of stuff?

In my client code i have a call:
Interface* i;
i->foo();

But if it is D2 in "i" i need to call bar() function in some cases.

Comment: are you inheriting D1 and D2 from Interface?

Comment: Yes, sorry, i forgot inheritance. Fixed.

Comment: You must define `virtual` destructor in `Interface`, otherwise you're in danger.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to call the bar function, you need to have a reference to an object that knows about bar.

So, either you reference a D2 object or your Interface must include a bar function. In the later case, your D1 must implement it as well, but the implementation can be empty or return an error value.

Comment: Ok, i have 1 interface and 5 implementations. And only in ONE implementation i have some specific functions. You said, that i need to implement it only in one case and in others write something like: void bar() {}. But i think it is not correct way to resolve that problem.

Comment: there is something wrong with your design, then. It is weird that you need one specific function at a specific point that make no sense at all for other implementations of the interface. When you use the interface, it should be in a context where all you need to know is your interface, and your interface should be able to do all you need from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using interfaces, you should move `bar` into a dedicated interface and then let clients use that:

```
class FooInterface {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class BarInterface {
public:
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

class D1 : public FooInterface {
public:
    void foo() {}
};

class D2 : public FooInterface,
           public BarInterface {
public:
    void foo() {}
    void bar() {}
};
```

Your client code needing a `bar` implementation could then take a `BarInterface`.

Comment: But in client apps i have code using only one interface.
For example an "array of Interfaces" and some code to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you inherit D1 and D2 from Interface. you can use cast to convert base pointer to derived object and use it, provided the base pointer points to `D2`

Comment: Client did not know anything about realization of interface.

Comment: @fryme: Yes client need not know anything about it

Answer (score 0):

If you are prepared to have some generic implementation in your interface you put an empty implementation of bar() in your interface:

```
class Interface
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void bar() {}
}

class D1 : public Interface
{
    void foo() {}
}

class D2 : public Interface
{
    void foo() {}
    void bar() {}
}
```

Now when you call Interface i* = blah; i->bar(); if i is a D1 it does nothing, if i is a D2 it will do something D2 specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
class _interface
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class _abstract : public _interface
{
public:
    _abstract(){}
    virtual ~_abstract(){};

    virtual void foo() = 0;
    int get_type()
    {
        return i_type;
    }

protected:
    int i_type;
};

class D1 : public _abstract
{
public:
    D1(){
        i_type = 1;
    }
    ~D1(){}

    void foo() {
        // do something
    }
};

class D2 : public _abstract
{
public:
    D2(){
        i_type = 2;
    }
    ~D2(){}

    void foo() {
        // do something
    }

    void bar() {
        // do something
    }
};
int main()
{
    D1 d_one;
    D2 d_two;

    _abstract* ab = &d_one;
    cout << ab->get_type() << "D1" << endl;

    ab = &d_two;
    cout << ab->get_type() << "D2" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You can identify which child by get_type(). So, you know what time you can use bar(). I don't what is the best approach.